# What can I do with all my Toast?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

I have a toaster that gives me 3 toast a day. Toast by itself is not very tasty and I only get one adventure if I eat it. Needless to say, I want to improve my toast-eating experiences.

What can I do with this toast? Can I combine it with things to make it tastier and more awesome?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you manage to get your hands on some jam, you can spread it on your toast for extra yumminess. Now, you'll find several different kinds of jam in the Kingdom (Loathingers are famed for their jam delicacies after all), each with its own unique taste.

If you go snorkeling or SCUBA diving, you might be able to find [jamfish jam](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Jamfish_jam). Spreading this on your toast and eating it will make you [more musically inclined](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Jammin%27).

Elves, on the other hand, are connoisseurs of jam, though their tastes might differ quite a lot from yours. They make jam from [space](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Space_jam), [cars](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Traffic_jam) and [mistletoe](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Toe_jam).

Comment: Is it jam? Or is it jelly? Either way it's going in my belly.